# IIS Rewrite URL module Condition

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

In my C#/.NET project I'm using the Rewrite URL module. There I have a rewrite rule which matches a certain pattern. However, in some cases, when there's a word "proxy" in the URL I do not want that request to be rewritten. I know that it should be done in the Conditions section of my rule. However I'm not sure what exact pattern should be used there.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a new rule that checks for "proxy" in the URL as a condition. Action is "None", and make sure the "Stop processing of subsequent rules" is checked. And, make sure this rule is triggered before your rewrite rule.